# CSS in the html is not having any effect on the html page which I am converting into pdf using mpf

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I have one html page which I am converting into pdf using mpdf. The conversions works fine but the pdf is not reading the css in the html page.

The following is the mpdf class

```
class M_pdf {

    public $param;
    public $pdf;

    public function __construct($param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3')
   // public function __construct($param = "'c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0")
    {
        $this->param =$param;
        $this->pdf = new mPDF();
    }
```

The HTML page has the following style codes

```
<style>
     body{
                    width: 21cm;
                    height: 29.7cm;
                    margin-left:auto; 
                    margin-right:auto; 
                    font-family: 'Montserrat'
                }
                .quotation--summary--head{
                    color: #616161;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-size:30px;
                    padding-top: 14px;
                    padding-bottom: 10px;
                }  
                .heading h4{
                    color: #616161;
                    background-color: #ebedef;
                    padding: 20px 0px;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    margin-top: 0px;  
                    margin-bottom: 0px;
                    letter-spacing: 1px;
                }
</style>
```

The HTML page is okay it shows everything in the way I want it to be like. The problem arises when it gets converted to pdf.

This is how it shows in the pdf:

```
ELECTRICAL
ROOM1
241000
1
Case 1 NOTE : note for case1BRAND : brand1
500Sq.Ft x 100
50000
2
Case 2 NOTE : note for case2BRAND : brand2
500Sq.Ft x 120
60000
3
Case 3 NOTE : note for case3BRAND : brand3
```

Whereas the real HTML page looks like this and this is how I want the pdf to look like as well.

[image: Whereas the real HTML looks liek this]

Any help to sort out the issue is welcome.

Comment: Try to use as external css. Refer [this](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html) link.

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation for using mpdf with CSS: https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html Two things to look for: some of the CSS tags are dependent on the version of the plugin; others such as what you define for the body are not available at all, thus will probably get ignored;